# StackOverflow Careers: Country Limitation?

Tags: support, jobs

I'm attempting to post a job on StackOverflow careers. We are offering relocation and so have selected that the job be available worldwide.

However, on the payment page it says:

`Valid in these locations: Anywhere except United Kingdom, Austria, Germany, France.`

What does that mean? Does it mean that the job will not show in these countries? If so then that would be a problem because we want to advertise the job to people in these countries.

Comment: This does not relate to SO. For issues with Careers, either ask the SE support directly (by using the contact for or e-mail) or ask them on the SE meta, but this has nothing to do with SO itself.

Comment: Then why is there a `careers` tag? And why is it careers.stackoverflow.com (not .stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: it has nothing to do with the SO _community_, and the SE _staff_ are the only ones who can reliably answer your question. And if you actually look at the careers tag, you will find that all except for the latest 2 questions have already been migrated to meta.SE.

Comment: @l4mpi: because the *domain name* includes Stack Overflow, asking the question here is **fine too**. Staff will migrate it to MSE if necessary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters still, the only ones who can reliably answer this question are _SE staff_, unless OP wants anecdotes from other SO members who posted a Careers 2.0 job listing...

Comment: @l4mpi: experienced users can handle such support questions just fine; if someone figured out the answer already and post that that's helpful too. If wrong, staff can post a better answer or correct. It's how we've been conducting support for SO and SE for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

The disclaimer you saw saying where it was valid refers only to the insertion of the job on the job board.  Basically, when a candidate comes to careers.stackoverflow.com and runs a search, your job will only appear in search results if they search the location where your job is listed.

Separate from insertion is the advertising on Stack Overflow.  When you selected World Wide, you are selecting the advertising region that controls who sees your ad on Stack Overflow.  Your ad will be biased towards the location of your actual office/job, and will gain further distribution constrained only by the advertising region.  So in your case, it would receive distribution on all of SO not constrained by any location due to picking World Wide.

Disclaimer:  This answer is unlikely to still be valid starting early next year when we give employers more control over the location their ads appear, and allow them to more easily separate advertising and insertion concerns.